# Whats the best way to make & animate Crater/s in eevee 9.2

Tags: modeling, animation, eevee-render-engine

I want to make and animate craters formation. I've tried boolean, which allows me to animate them, but they don't look as good and don't add the collection of dirt that gathers at the top of the crater when formed, and I've tried a crater height map, which does look the best add does provide some animation ability but not flex ability, like if I wanted to add more than one and some overlap. I know there's a way in cycles, but I'm only using EEVEE to animate and render in.

I like Boolean because I can change the texture of the crater and keyframe it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend dynamic paint, set to displacement. If that doesn’t work, try using a displacement modifier with a color ramp on the texture to make it the right shape for a crater.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it when I get the chance.